# How to create a OnItemClickListener for custom list view when passing data from php using json

Tags: java, onitemclicklistener, custom-lists

I am creating an app where a list of hotels will be shown, all the data is coming from **MySQL** using **JSON** and **PHP**, I created the custom `list view` by extending the base adapter to a custom one, but I am not able to implement a `OnItemClickListener` for the `listview`, as i want to show the Hotel Name of that row in `Toast` whenever the user clicks on a row of list view. I tried various example available on internet, but i just doesn't work.

Adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapterHotel extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<WorldsBillionaires> billionairesItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


    public CustomListAdapterHotel(Activity activity, List<WorldsBillionaires> billionairesItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.billionairesItems = billionairesItems;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return billionairesItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return billionairesItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_hotel, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        //NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView hotel_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hotel_name);
        TextView zone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.zone);
        TextView contact_person = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_person);
        TextView contact_number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
        TextView btc_direct = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btcdirect);

        // getting billionaires data for the row
        WorldsBillionaires m = billionairesItems.get(position);


        // name
        hotel_name.setText(String.valueOf(m.getHotel_Name()));

        zone.setText(String.valueOf(m.getHotel_Zone()));

        contact_person.setText(String.valueOf(m.getContact_Person()));

        contact_number.setText(String.valueOf(m.getContact_Number()));

        btc_direct.setText(String.valueOf(m.getBtc_Direct()));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Model

```
public class WorldsBillionaires {

    private String hotel_name,hotel_zone,contact_person,contact_number,btc_direct;

    public WorldsBillionaires(String hotel_name, String hotel_zone, String contact_person, String contact_number, String btc_direct) {
        this.hotel_name=hotel_name;
        this.hotel_zone=hotel_zone;
        this.contact_person=contact_person;
        this.contact_number=contact_number;
        this.btc_direct=btc_direct;
    }
    public WorldsBillionaires() {
    }
    public String getZone() {
        return zone;
    }

    public void setZone(String zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }
    public String getHotel_Name() {
        return hotel_name;
    }

    public void setHotel_Name(String hotel_name) {
        this.hotel_name = hotel_name;
    }

    public String getHotel_Zone() {
        return hotel_zone;
    }

    public void setHotel_Zone(String hotel_zone) {
        this.hotel_zone = hotel_zone;
    }

    public String getContact_Person() {
        return contact_person;
    }

    public void setContact_Person(String contact_person) {
        this.contact_person = contact_person;
    }

    public String getContact_Number() {
        return contact_number;
    }

    public void setContact_Number(String contact_number) {
        this.contact_number = contact_number;
    }

    public String getBtc_Direct() {
        return btc_direct;
    }

    public void setBtc_Direct(String btc_direct) {
        this.btc_direct = btc_direct;
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class ShowHotel extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // Billionaires json url
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<WorldsBillionaires> worldsBillionairesList = new ArrayList<WorldsBillionaires>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapterHotel adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_hotel);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapterHotel(this, worldsBillionairesList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();


        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest billionaireReq = new JsonArrayRequest("http://192.168.247.1/AdminBihar/getHotel.php?zone="+methods.zone,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                WorldsBillionaires worldsBillionaires = new WorldsBillionaires();
                                worldsBillionaires.setHotel_Name(obj.getString("hotel_name"));
                                worldsBillionaires.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                worldsBillionaires.setHotel_Zone(obj.getString("zone"));
                                worldsBillionaires.setContact_Person(obj.getString("contact_person"));
                                worldsBillionaires.setContact_Number(obj.getString("contact_number"));
                                worldsBillionaires.setBtc_Direct(obj.getString("btc_direct"));

                                // adding Billionaire to worldsBillionaires array
                                worldsBillionairesList.add(worldsBillionaires);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(billionaireReq);


    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so after you get json data, in activity that shows your list do something like this:

```
public class DisplayListView extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;

protected void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_list_view);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    hotelAdapter = new CustomListAdapterHotel (this, R.layout.row_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(hotelAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

            Model stuff = (Model) hotelAdapter.getItem(position);
            String hotelName = stuff.getHotel_Name(); 

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), hotelName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

there, this worked for me :)